# How to add a variable in kotlin that saves user input?

Tags: kotlin, input

I am trying to make a calculator with kotlin and I need a variable that contains the number the user types in. for example in python I would type num = input("type you're number here").
I have tried this and it does not work in the kotlin programming language. how do I do it on kotlin.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the readLine() fuction for getting input from keyboard, and hold its output in some variable of the String type.

```kotlin
fun main() {
    print("Enter text: ")

    val stringInput = readln()
    println("You entenred: $stringInput")
}
```

References:

1. [readln](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/readln.html)
2. [Kotlin Basic Input/Output](https://www.programiz.com/kotlin-programming/input-output)
3. [The !! operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#the-operator)

Comment: `readln()` is preferable to `readLine()` for this purpose.

Comment: Would @Tenfour04 tell us why?

Comment: It’s in the docs of the two functions. `readLine()` is not limited to console user input, which is why it returns a nullable string and you end up having to use the nasty `!!` when using it for console input. If you just want to accept user-typed input, there’s no chance of an “end-of-file” null being returned, which is why `readln()` returns a non-nullable string.